# UIViewのExtensionで変数を追加したい

Tags: swift, ios

タイトルの通り、実装しようと思い調べていましたら、Extensionではメソッドなどは追加できるが変数は追加できない、といった記事を見つけまして、自分でクラスを追加しなければならない、とのようなことが書いてありました。しかしイマイチ方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

単に「変数を追加したい」ではなく、その変数を用いて実現したいことを記述していただければ、よりその目的に沿った的確な回答があるかもしれません。

あなたが調べられた「自分でクラスを追加しなければならない」と言うのはサブクラス化のことを言っているのではないかと思います。

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var myInt: Int = 0
    var myString: String? = nil
}
```

このように`UIView`を継承したクラスを作ってやれば(`MyView`なんて名前は実際のアプリではより適切な名前に置き換えてください)、`MyView`クラスのインスタンスは`UIView`の一種として使用できます。

ただ、`UIView`のサブクラス化にはいろいろ難しい部分もあり、かなりのベテラン開発者でも苦労することが多いです。最初に書いたように、特定の方法論にこだわらずに「本当は何がしたいのか」をご説明頂ければ、はるかに簡潔で優れた解法が見つかるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね、詳しい説明を全く書いていなくてすみません。

Comment: 実際は、TinderライクなUIの中で、1枚1枚のカードがViewでできていて、そのカードに例えばView.ImageId,のように変数を保持したいです。

Comment: @hanachan1026 さん、MVCという言葉は聞いたことがあると思いますが、iOSアプリのようにMVCを標榜するフレームワークの鉄則の一つに「Viewをデータの置き場にするな」と言うのがあります。あなたの例で言うと「1枚1枚のカード」をViewとは独立してモデル化してしまい、imageIdのように画面に直接表示されないデータはモデルの方に保持すべきです。逆に`imageId`から取得した画像データは実際に表示される内容ですから、そう言うものはViewの側に保持した方がいいと言うことになります。『「1枚1枚のカード」はViewとは無関係の`Card`クラスにしてその中に`imageId`を持つ。それを表示しやすくするための`CardView`は別途設計する。』と言う方が良いのではないでしょうか。`CardView`に相当するクラスは画面ごとに表示内容に合わせて必要でしょうが、`UICollectionView`などは、カスタマイズで色々な表示スタイルに対応できるので、(`UIView`ではなく)`UICollectionViewCell`をサブクラス化した方が良いかもしれません。とりあえずは一つの画面だけでもデザインを完成させ、それをどのように実現するかという観点で(わからない点があれば)改めてご質問を書かれた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: tagプロパティを使うのはダメですかね?...

Comment: @ura14h さん、`tag`はプログラマー側に使用方法が委ねられていますから、それを画像の情報を保持するModelとの紐付けに使うのは私的にはアリだと思っています。私のコメント中にある`imageId`をViewに持っちゃダメと言うのはちょっと誤解を招いたかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

Associated Objectsを使って実現できます

```
var hogeKey: UInt8 = 0

extension UIView {
    var hoge: String? {
        get {
            guard let object = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &hogeKey) as? String else {
                return nil
            }
            return object
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &hogeKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```